# Disabling swing components based on radio buttons when program starts

Tags: java, swing

I want to disable certain swing components based on a button group of radio buttons. One of the radio buttons is selected initially, but it doesn't disable the components until one of the buttons is clicked. How can i make it so that a text field is off by default?

I have this of it helps.

```
        private void cCipherActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if (cCipher.isSelected()) {
        cipherText.setEnabled(false);
        cipherLetterSelect.setEnabled(true);
    }
}                                       

private void vCipherActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if (vCipher.isSelected()) {
        cipherLetterSelect.setEnabled(false);
        cipherText.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *`How can i make it so that a text field is off by default?`* invoke `setEnable(false)` right after it's initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understood, it's quite simple: consider cipherText for example, you can create at the start of the class the JTextField instance:

```
JTextField cipherText = new JTextField();
```

and then in the constructor of the specific class you set it to disabled

```
public MyClass(){

    cipherText.setEnabled(false);  

}
```